# I want to select (Event) in which all the (Users) are registered in event

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```cs
string value = "bse161063";
var inst = db.User_Register_Events.Where(c => c.UserTable.User_id == value).Select(x => x.UserTable.User_id).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

I have an issue in the below given query.

```cs
var userid = db.User_Register_Events.Where(c=>c.EventTable.Event_Title.Contains(value)).ToList();
var query = List.Where(UserTable => User_Id == value);
```

I want to select the (events) which are registered by a specific (user).

[image]

[image: Database schema]

Comment: It is hard to help, as I can't understand what the tables look like. However, it appears you would be getting a list back for the variable 'userid', maybe you need a FirstOrDefault() here? Same for the query of the usertable. I would think it would read like this: db.UserTable.Where(x=>x.User_Id == value).FIrstOrDefault()

Comment: I have add the database schema. please check post, so you can get better idea..i am working on User_Register_Table to get the data what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly by your screenshot what you're asking, then I gather you want to get all events for a user based on a search of the user's `Name` in the UserTables table. In that case the following should do the trick. It starts off in the UserTables table, then makes two hops to get the event Details from the EventTables table.

```
string userName = "Muhammad";
db.UserTables.Where(ut => ut.Name == userName).Select(ut => ut.User_Register_Events.Select(ure => ure.EventTable)).ToList();
```

If you're getting the events by just the user's Id then the query would be somewhat simpler, as you can start off in the User_Register_Event table like so

```
string userId = "bse161063";
db.User_Register_Events.Where(ure => ure.UserTableId == userId).Select(ure => ure.EventTable).ToList();
```

Ultimately, both queries will return a collection of `EventTable` based on the Select() projection here.

Comment: var returnEvents=db.User_Register_Events.Where(ure => ure.UserTable.User_id == value).Select(ure => ure.EventTable).ToList();